# Would most people benefit from psychotherapy?

Tags: abnormal-psychology, clinical-psychology

At least in my country, undergoing psychotherapy is perceived negatively.
People in my country perceive people as either healthy (normal), or mad and in need of a psychologist. My perception is different. I think most people would benefit from psychological therapy.

**Does the evidence support the idea that most people would benefit from psychotherapy?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The same methods that psychotherapy utilizes to help people overcome psychological problems are used in **coaching** to help healthy and successful persons to become even more successful and feel even more better.

So, yes, **everyone can benefit from psychotherapy**, you just don't have to call it that, which might make it easier for most people to accept it.

If I were a psychotherapist, I would call my service "mental fitness" and advertise it in the same manner as gyms advertise their services as a lifestyle ("Be sexy and successful!") instead of a health product ("Fight obesity!").